# How to simulate and draw electric fields in Matlab with contourf?

Tags: matlab, plot

I'd like to know how to draw a graph with 2 electric charges Q and -Q and their total E, for a specific point (eg (4,5)), with contour f..
My M-file actually scans the area (from -3x to 3x) and calculates E for every spot, stores it in a table, but after this, I don't know how to use contourf to draw it..

```
syms i
syms j
syms d
d=input('dwse thn timi tou d,ths apostashs')
j=0
i=0
for j=-d:d/1000:d

    j=j+1

for i=-d:d/1000:d

    i=i+1
    z=(i,j)

end, end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on Coulomb's law, the electric field created by a single, discrete charge q at a distance r is given by:

E=q/(4*pi*e0*r.^2);

If you have several charges you can use the superposition principle and add the contribution of each charge.

The only thing left to do is to create a grid to compute the electrical field. For this you can use tha Matlab function `meshgrid`.

A simple example in Matlab would be:

```
k=1/4/pi/8.854e-12;
d=2;
q=[-1 1];
x=[-d/2 d/2];
y=[0 0];

dx=0.01;
X=(-d:dx:d);
Y=(-d:dx:d);
[X Y]=meshgrid(X,Y);

E=zeros(size(X));

for i=1:numel(q)
    r=sqrt((X-x(i)).^2+(Y-y(i)).^2);
    E=E+k*q(i)./r.^2;
end

E(isinf(E))=NaN;

figure;
contourf(X,Y,E);
axis image;
```

Hope it helps you. You can read the documentation of `contourf` to tweak the plot to your needs.

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply and your time..!
could you please add some comments? i don't understand how to modify it to calculate E, and draw it with different colours depending on the field strength, for every spot..
i get this : http://img513.imageshack.us/img513/4607/matlabpap.jpg

Answer (score 1):

You need to give some more information in your question: What is the problem you are having? What have you tried?

However, assuming that `z(i,j)` is your electric field calculated on a 2d grid, just call [`contourf`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/contourf.html) after your `for` loops as

```
contourf(z)
```

Comment: i actually dont know how to fill the array with a loop..
there are 2 charges -Q(-d/2,0) and Q(d/2,0), their distance is d.
i have to make an array with the result of Etotal for every point in  x(-2d,2d) y(-2d,2d), and then use contourf.. i am lost :/

Comment: @zwoskasere Well you need some idea of the equations you are solving/using. This sounds to me like a homework - is it?

Comment: i have the equations, i just dont know how to fill an array within a loop on matlab.. its physics homework